# mpdf - Printing a php strings

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm using mpdf in order to print a PHP code, but in the PDF result it shows me the code, and it should show me one star.

Code:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$html = '<?php $obj = json_decode($myJSON,true);
                foreach($obj as $data){ 
                    if($data[\'llave\'] == \'Autoritario\')
                    {   ?>

                <?php for
                    ($i=0;$i<$data[\'stars\'];$i++){ 
                        echo \'&#9733\'; 

                    } ?><?php 

                    }}

                    ?>

                            ';


$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();

?>
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the string:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
ob_start();
$obj = json_decode($myJSON,true);
foreach($obj as $data){ 
    if($data['llave'] == 'Autoritario'){
        for($i=0;$i<$data['stars']; $i++){ 
            echo "&#9733"; 
        } 
    }
}
$html = ob_get_contents();//get the content
ob_end_clean();//erase the output buffer
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: I would say: either $html.= or echo with ob_start/get_contents. This doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.